# MATLAB don't show x tick labels on subplots

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot

I'm plotting 4 subplots, and for some reason, the x axis tick labels of the top 2 subplots don't appear on the figure (The x axis labels should be hours from datetime).

My code is:

```
figure
subplot(2,4,1)
plot(dateval,Height,'b','LineWidth',1)
datetick('x','HH:MM') %change the axis to time format
xlim([736886.619552373 736886.692032847]) %Limits
set(gca, 'FontName', 'Bookman','FontSize',7);
xlabel('Time','FontSize',7,'FontWeight','normal','Color','k','FontName','Bookman')
ylabel('GPS Height $[m]$','FontSize',7,'FontWeight','normal','Color','k','FontName','Bookman','Interpreter','latex')


subplot(2,4,2)
plot(dateval,Pressure,'b','LineWidth',1)
datetick('x','HH:MM') %change the axis to time format
xlim([736886.619552373 736886.692032847]) %Limits
xlabel('Time','FontSize',7,'FontWeight','normal','Color','k','FontName','Bookman')
ylabel('Sensor Pressure $[mb]$','FontSize',7,'FontWeight','normal','Color','k','FontName','Bookman','Interpreter','latex')
set(gca, 'FontName', 'Bookman','FontSize',7);


subplot(2,4,[5 6])
scatter(Pressure,Height,3,'b','*'); %Number is the size of dots
h=lsline;
set(h,'color','r','LineWidth',2);
R=corrcoef([Pressure,Height]);
Fit = polyfit(Pressure,Height,1);
ylabel('GPS Height $$[m]$$','FontSize',7,'FontWeight','normal','Color','k','FontName','Bookman','Interpreter','latex');
xlabel('Pressure $[mb]$','FontSize',7,'FontWeight','normal','Color','k','FontName','Bookman','Interpreter','latex');
xlim([1003 1015])
ylim([0 90])
set(gca, 'FontName', 'Bookman','FontSize',7);
box on

 subplot(2,4,[3,4,7,8])
image( imread('TripMap.jpg') );
set(gca,'xtick',[])
set(gca,'xticklabel',[])
set(gca,'ytick',[])
set(gca,'yticklabel',[])
```

The figure:

[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you add your figure?

Comment: Yes - I've edited my post

Comment: If you plot each of those two separately, does it plot? Cus if it looks right, then you probably just need to format your ticks. Otherwise, there is something going on with maybe your xlim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the order of these two lines:

```
datetick('x','HH:MM') %change the axis to time format
xlim([736886.619552373 736886.692032847]) %Limits
```

To:

```
xlim([736886.619552373 736886.692032847]) %Limits
datetick('x','HH:MM') %change the axis to time format
```

Comment: It worked for the ticks! But now the xlim command doesn't work

Comment: change to datetick('x','HH:MM','keeplimits')

Comment: It worked after I did this and move the two lines after the "set(gca.." line! Thanks